# What query string is used to display products in commerce kickstart?

Tags: 7, commerce, database

I am creating a php script to display all the products from commerce kickstart database

But the image is in a table called `file_managed` and the products are in `commerce_products` and i cant seem to figure it out. what query is used to display the products in commerce kicker or how do i select all the product and images from the database using sql?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function commerce_product_load which is documented [here](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!product!commerce_product.module/function/commerce_product_load/DC). I am sorry if you are saying Drupal is not loaded and you have to use a straight php query.